# Calculation of channel autocorrelation for LMMSE

Tags: filters, digital-communications, autocorrelation, ofdm, channel-estimation

I am currently trying to implement an LMMSE estimator/equalizer for a python based ofdm receiver. The actual reception is done with a SDR and iq-samples are stored in a file for the "ofdm-receiver" process in Python.

### LMMSE theory

I've read through a multitude of resources. The final (simplified) formula for LMMSE i am trying to implement is ([Edfors et. Al.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/501446)):

$\hat{H}_{LMMSE} = R_{HH} (R_{HH} + \frac{\beta}{SNR}I)^{-1} \hat{H}_{LS}$

$R_{hh}$ denotes the Channel autocorrelation, $\beta$ is a modulation mapping dependent constant, $SNR$ the signal to noise ratio, $I$ an identity Matrix and $\hat{H}_{LS}$ the Least Squares channel estimate.

I've accomplished the computation for all the elements successfully (I think) except for the **channel autocorrelation matrix**. I am not shure how to compute this matrix correctly. As I dont have the true channel coefficients $H$, I intend to use the estimate $\hat{H}_{LS}$ instead. That LS-estimate is obtained by using the Long Training Sequence (LTS) from the preamble. $R_{HH}$ is computed as:

$R_{HH} = E\{HH^H\}$ 
with $(.)^H$ beeing the Hermetian operation.

I am working with a SISO system, so I only have **one vector** of estimated channel coefficients $\hat{H}_{LS}$ with dimensions $(64\times1)$. I've tried using numpys **correlate** function as well as the **corrcoef** function. So far, the resulting $\hat{H}_{LMMSE}$ is always incorrect and leads to worse equalization than using only the $\hat{H}_{LS}$. I would try to implement it manually, but I dont know how I would go about that. I know, that for equally propable outcomes of a random variable, the expectation simplifies to the arithmetic mean of all outcomes. So from [Wikipedia: Autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) and [this StackExchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853808/product-of-a-vector-and-its-transpose-projections) i conclude:

$R_{HH} = E[HH^H] = E\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}H_1 \\H_2\\ \vdots \\ H_n  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\bar{H_1} \bar{H_2} \dots \bar{H_n}\end{bmatrix} 
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
E[H_{1}\bar{H_{1}}]\quad E[H_{1}\bar{H_{2}}]\quad \cdots\quad E[H_{1}\bar{H_{n}}]\\
E[H_{2}\bar{H_{1}}]\quad E[H_{2}\bar{H_{2}}]\quad \cdots\quad E[H_{2}\bar{H_{n}}]\\
\vdots\quad\quad\quad  \vdots\quad\quad \ddots\quad\quad \vdots\\
E[H_{n}\bar{H_{1}}]\quad E[H_{n}\bar{H_{2}}]\quad \cdots\quad E[H_{n}\bar{H_{n}}]\\
\end{bmatrix}$

For complex valued random variable $Z$.
I've come to understand ([StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642291/expectation-operator-on-a-matrix)), that $H_1 H_2 \dots H_n$ are not the actual realizations of my random variable $H$ but rather random variables on their own.

### My Question

1. I don't really understand how to compute/implement the auto-correlation matrix $R_{HH}$. I saw that one would have to estimate it (Wiener Filter?) but I don't understand how to apply it to my ofdm case.
2. What dimensions should the identity matrix $I$ have?
3. My $SNR$ calculation follows ([Edfors et. Al.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/501446)):
   $SNR = \frac{E[\mid x_k \mid^2]}{\sigma_n^2}$ 
   Where I interpreted the term in the numerator as the signal energy. Is that correct?

**NOTE** Maybe it is useful know that I don't have to realize a real time performance, since I am working on prerecorded data.

Thank you for your time and help!
Cheers
Lucas

Comment: 1) you need to assume a multi-path channel model, from which $R_{HH}$ can be derived. Edfors et al, in the paper you cited, did calculate the autocorrelation for Rayleigh multi-tap channels.

2) same dimension of $R_{HH}$

3) it depends what do you mean by 'signal'. The $\mathbf{X}$ is well-defined in the paper. I would say that this is the average power of constellation.

Comment: @AlexTP Thank you for the insight. So in practice $R_{HH}$ is just calculated via a channel model that is assumed to fit the situation (like rayleigh multi-tap)? In the case of the paper (Edfors et. al.) (I assume you read it), the formula in Appendix B for $r_{m,n}$ gives the matrix elements?

Comment: yes and yes. The key component is $R_{HH} = \mathbb{E}(H^H H)$, with $\mathbb{E}()$ mean expected value. Therefore If you do not know channel statistics, you can estimate $R_{HH}$ by using, say, thousands realizations of $H$.

Comment: for the estimation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_of_covariance_matrices